# Trying to make a simple packet router in C on Linux. select() idles indefinitely and I don't know why

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

Like the title says I'm trying to make a packet router, but it gets stuck on select().  I am using a Mininet environment with 4 hosts (h1, h2, h3, r0), 3 switches (s1, s2, s3) and 3 interfaces (r0-eth1, r0-eth2, r0-eth3).  I am compiling the c code and running the executable on r0.  Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sock1, sock2, sock3;
int status = 0;
fd_set readfds;
int buffer[256];



// Create 3 sockets
if ((sock1 = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP))) < 0){
    perror("socket() failed");
    exit(1);
}
if ((sock2 = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP))) < 0){
    perror("socket() failed");
    exit(1);
}
if ((sock3 = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_IP))) < 0){
    perror("socket() failed");
    exit(1);
}

// Bind sockets to interfaces
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "r0-eth1");
if (setsockopt(sock1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
perror("setsockopt() inf config failed");
exit(1);
}
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "r0-eth2");
if (setsockopt(sock2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
perror("setsockopt() inf config failed");
exit(1);
}
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "r0-eth3");
if (setsockopt(sock3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
perror("setsockopt() inf config failed");
exit(1);
}


//Setup select
FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(sock1, &readfds);
FD_SET(sock2, &readfds);
FD_SET(sock3, &readfds);

status = select( sock3 + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

while(1)
{
    // Check select
    if (status > 0) {
        // Read IP datagram
        if (FD_ISSET(sock1, &readfds)) {
            struct sockaddr_in sockAddr;
            socklen_t sockLen = sizeof(sockAddr);
            memset(&sockAddr, 0, sockLen);
            sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            int bufLen = recvfrom(sock1, buffer, 65535, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sockAddr, (socklen_t *)&sockLen);
        }
    }
}
```

I run it with this command:

```
    r0 ./router &
```

Then I do a

```
    pingall
```

To see if the hosts can  reach each other.  My executable gets stuck on select() and never moves on.  During the pingall h1, h2, and h3 can all reach r0, but all other packets are dropped.  I know I haven't completed the routing part yet, but I can't really move on to it until this gets solved.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You have to reinitialize the fd_sets inside the loop. (they are modified by select()) And: you need a loop around select()

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your problem is pretty simple.  Note this code segment:

```
     status = select( sock3 + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

while(1)
{
    // Check select
    if (status > 0) {
        // Read IP datagram
        if (FD_ISSET(sock1, &readfds)) {
            struct sockaddr_in sockAddr;
            socklen_t sockLen = sizeof(sockAddr);
            memset(&sockAddr, 0, sockLen);
            sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
            int bufLen = recvfrom(sock1, buffer, 65535, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sockAddr, (socklen_t *)&sockLen);
        }
    }
}
```

You set up to use `select()`.  You then enter a `while(1)` loop and check to see what's going on with `status`... but you never call select again, never update the value of status, and never allow the `while` loop to end.

Additionally, when using `select()` and `FD_SET`, you will need to reset `FD_SET` after each signal.

Comment: I moved the `select()`, `FD_ZERO()`, and the `FD_SET()`s inside the while loop.  I put some basic `printf()` checks around the `select()` and it still never moves past that point.  I also tried putting a timeout on the `select` and it still stays stuck on that function well passed the timeout length.

Comment: Are you certain that packets are arriving?

Comment: I believe they are.  The output of pingall looks like this: `h1 -> X X r0` `h2 -> X X r0` `h3 -> X X r0 ` `r0 -> h1 h2 h3 ` `*** Results: 50% dropped (6/12 received)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check if the packets are being sent to the hosts or not.